# iOS 7 UIWebView not rendering

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios7

I'm porting my app to iOS 7 and I have a problem with UIWebView in iOS 7.
I load local html string in it with this code:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: DOCUMENTS_DIRECTORY];
[self.descWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
```

It works perfectly on iOS 6 and prior but on iOS 7 it doesn't rendering and the UIWebView is still white. And this message appears in console:

```
void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate
(webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:)
failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
```

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: `[self.descWebView loadHTMLString:@"test" baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:DOCUMENTS_DIRECTORY]];` - something like this works fine for me. The issue may come from your `html` content, or from some `UIWebViewDelegate` methods that you've implemented

Comment: Interesting is, that if I archive app and install .ipa in device it doesn't works on first run but if I close the app from multitasking and open app again it works great...

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue! On iOS7, when I install the .ipa file, my webview does not work with the same error mentioned above. Killing and restarting the app fixes the problem! Have you found a solution/workaround?

Comment: I have the same problem and in my case it's related to use of Critterism SDK. If disable it everything works well.

Comment: Do you still have the problem? We don't use Critterism on our side.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well, and am not using Critterism

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned by @zaplitny, I had to update Crittercism to the latest version (4.1.0) for this problem to go away.

Comment: Is this true? I can't believe it is the bug tracker that cause the bug!

Comment: This is true. There was a limitation in the 4.0.x version of Crittercism which made it incompatible with UIWebView in iOS 7. This has been fixed in all 4.1.x versions.

Comment: I'm using Crittercism 4.1.1 (RC), and I have this issue. It seems quite intermittent, so I can't confirm whether or not it is a Crittercism issue by disabling/enabling it.

Comment: Updating to 4.1.2 didn't fix this.

Comment: Updating to 4.3.0 didn't fix it for me

Comment: I just got in touch with crittercism support.  Apparently the issue is resolved in [4.3.1](https://app.crittercism.com/downloads/release_notes/ios/4.3.1)

Comment: I can confirm @nacross's comment. The fix is outlined in the Crittercism release notes: https://app.crittercism.com/downloads/release_notes/ios/4.3.1

Answer (score 9):

There was a problem with older version of the Crittercism library which caused this. As others have alluded to in comments, this bug was fixed in the 4.3.1 version of the Crittercism SDK.

https://app.crittercism.com/downloads/release_notes/ios/4.3.1 :

> fix: Workaround for apps experiencing UIWebViews failing to load data
>   on first launch when running on iOS 7. This only occurs in apps that
>   subclass UIWebView, and Crittercism has filed a bug report with Apple.
>   Note - Be aware that while your application may not directly subclass
>   UIWebView, this is done in many common 3rd party libraries such as the
>   Google AdMob and Millenial Media SDKs.

Comment: The important part for me was "Be aware that while your application may not directly subclass UIWebView, this is done in many common 3rd party libraries such as the Google AdMob and Millenial Media SDKs".  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

For those of us who updated Crittercism to the version 4.1.2 hoping that it would solve the issue but it didn't. I can offer quite an ugly but simple solution: create and initialize `UIWebView` before calling `[Crittercism enableWithAppID:@"***...***"];`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {
    ...
    UIWebView* fakeWebView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-1, -1, 1, 1)] autorelease];
    [fakeWebView loadHTMLString:@"<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><body>I need Crittercism</body></html>" baseURL:nil];
    [mainViewController.view addSubview:fakeWebView];

    [Crittercism enableWithAppID:@"***...***"];
    ...
}
```

This trick allowed me not only to get rid of a described problem, but also slightly speed up the first initialization of a real `UIWebView`.

Comment: This works, but it's not required to load content in the UIWebView or to add it as a subview. Just initialise a UIWebView and it will have the same effect.

Comment: This is completely fixed in Crittercism version 4.3.1

Answer (score 3):

I had this error appearing trying to display admob ads, when ever crittercism was enabled I would get that error in the logs, incidentally the ads were not displaying either.

To fix it, I disabled crittercism instrumentation, this might not be an option for everyone.

```
[Crittercism enableWithAppID:@"your_app_id" andDelegate:nil andURLFilters:nil disableInstrumentation:YES];
```

If not simply creating a webview (You don't need to add it as a subview) as suggested by others seems to work for me as well.

```
[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-1, -1, 1, 1)]
[Crittercism enableWithAppID:@"your_app_id"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `product --> clean`.  It can't hurt.  When you run an app it will only `replace/compile` the files that changed.  Some times the `xCode` bugs up and doesn't compile a changed file.  Product clean deletes old versions of the compiled code so next time you build it will have been all from the last compile. Again you have nothing to lose by doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same problem you are. I have tried:

- moving the load request from the viewDidLoad to the viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear, this did not help anything
- tried reloading the webview after the load request was made. still nothing
- tried changing the URL creation from URLWithString to fileURLWithPath and still nothing

What is even more strange is that none of the delegate methods fire when the page doesnt load. it is almost as if the web view doesnt even attempt to load the page. Yet, like you said, if you close the app from the multitask view and reopen it, everything works fine.

were you able to figure out a way around this or found a solution?

Comment: Did you find a way to fix it?

Comment: i did, the problem was caused by crittercism. i fixed it by switching from using the enableWithAppID: method to the enableWithAppID:anDelegate:andURLFilters:disableInstrumentation: method. Passing nil into the delegate and filters parameters and true for disabling instrumentation.

Comment: Looks like it works. But what does "disableInstrumentation" parameter mean? I didn't find any information about this parameter in Crittercism documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues with my PhoneGap application on IOS7, i had to Redraw the UI of the page on "viewDidAppear" or "Pageshow" using the below code and this worked for me.

```
 $(".cls_div_page_content").redraw();
 jQuery.fn.redraw = function() {
   return this.hide(0, function(){$(this).show()});
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

many times this error can come in case u are using something that is not available in that particular iOS version..
for example

NSString *test=@"test this";

[test containsString:@"test"];

use of containsString in iOS 7.1 will give you the same following error, but it will work fine in iOS 8.0,

void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:)
failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue too. It seems the problem is caused when certain 3rd party libraries are linked, but I am not even sure exactly which one was responsible in my case. I didn't have Crittercism in my app.

What fixed it for me was the suggestion I found [here on Apple's Dev Forum](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23685429#23685429) to instantiate a `UIWebView` early.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // In a severe case of WTF: some 3rd party libs (exact culprit unknown) can cause webviews to stop
    // showing anything on iOS 7, and instead have console warnings every 10 seconds that look like:
    // void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
    // Just instantiating an UIWebView before any of the 3rd party libs kick in is enough to fix it.
    // Don't know why, but it works.
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"8.0")) {
        UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
        webView.delegate = nil; // Do something with webView to silence warning
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using Parse SDK with the 1.6.x version under iOS7/iOS8 and subclass UIWebView, same problem will appear if you are using `PFInstallation saveInBackground` method.

Solution is to delay call `saveInBackground`, e.g.:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 3.f * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
});
```