# MPMoviePlayerController randomly doesn't play movie

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm having a problem with MPMoviePlayerController on iOS sometimes playing a video (loaded from a local file) and sometimes just failing silently. The *same* video launched at the beginning of the app just the same way every time. When it fails, it doesn't notify in any way, I just see a black screen.

Here's the code I'm using to play the video (this is a cocos2d-x based game and I attach the movie player controller as a child of the EAGLView):

```
- (void)playVideo:(NSString*)filePath
{
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    _moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    EAGLView* view = [EAGLView sharedEGLView];

    _moviePlayerController.view.frame = view.bounds;
    _moviePlayerController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    _moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    _moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    _moviePlayerController.shouldAutoplay = NO;

    [view addSubview:_moviePlayerController.view];

    [_moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
}

- (void)videoFinished:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [_moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [_moviePlayerController release];
}

- (void)videoLoadStateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if ((_moviePlayerController.loadState & MPMovieLoadStatePlayable) != 0)
    {
        [_moviePlayerController play];
    }
}
```

When the playback fails, I get the following notifications:

- `MPMoviePlayerNowPlayingMovieDidChangeNotification`
- `MPMovieSourceTypeAvailableNotification`

And nothing else. When the playback works, I get these:

- `MPMoviePlayerNowPlayingMovieDidChangeNotification`
- `MPMovieSourceTypeAvailableNotification` (up to here, same as when it fails)
- `MPMovieMediaTypesAvailableNotification`
- `MPMovieMediaTypesAvailableNotification`
- `MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification`
- `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification`
- `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification`
- `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification`
- `MPMovieNaturalSizeAvailableNotification`
- `MPMoviePlayerReadyForDisplayDidChangeNotification`
- `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification`
- `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`

I've tried several different alternatives, including using a MPMoviePlayerViewController, but every time I get the same weird behavior. Any ideas?

Comment: @Salmo the "duplicated" lines you removed were actually intended as some of the notifications arrive several times. The list was showing all the notifications I get in the order I get them. Maybe I should have used a numbered list... Can you please revert your changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem ended up being totally unrelated to the symptoms...

It appears to be some sort of bug with Crittercism running on iOS 7. While looking into a debug message in our console (`"(webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:)
failed to return after waiting 10 seconds"`) we came across this question: [iOS 7 UIWebView not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066066/ios-7-uiwebview-not-rendering/19328839#19328839), which suggests installing an updated version of Crittercism. After doing that, our problem with video playback seems to be fixed.