# swift void SendDelegateMessage.. webView:decidePolicyForNavigationActionfailed to return after waiting 10 seconds... kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, xcode6

I create app with ios 7 and ios 8 compatible but UIWebview on ios 7 delegete never called and i get

> void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate
>   (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:)
>   failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode:
>   kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

I search on internet but no sollution
4 day trying with no lucky..

```
    class AWTncViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate{
 @IBOutlet weak var wv: UIWebView!

    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
        wv.delegate = nil

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.wv.delegate = self;
        let myHTMLString:String! = "<h1>Hello word!</h1>"
        self.wv.loadHTMLString(myHTMLString, baseURL: nil)
     }
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
       /* Test 2 still not load
         let myHTMLString:String! = "<h1>Hello word!</h1>"
        self.wv.loadHTMLString(myHTMLString, baseURL: nil)
       */
    }



    func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        //this never called
        println("shouldStartLoadWithRequest execute") 
        return true
    }

    func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
    {
        //this never called
    println("shouldStartLoadWithRequest execute")
         return true

    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView)
    {
       //this never called
        println("Start load")
    }
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView)
    {
        //this never called
        println("FinishLoad")
    }
    func webView(webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError)
    {
        //this never called
        println("didFailLoadWithError: \(error.description)")
    }





    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }



}
```

I read this :[iOS 7 UIWebView not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066066/ios-7-uiwebview-not-rendering)

But i'm not use Crittercism

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue too. It seems the problem is caused when certain 3rd party libraries are linked, but I am not even sure exactly which one was responsible in my case.

What fixed it for me was the suggestion I found [here on Apple's Dev Forum](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23685429#23685429) to instantiate a `UIWebView` early.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // In a severe case of WTF: some 3rd party libs (exact culprit unknown) can cause webviews to stop
    // showing anything on iOS 7, and instead have console warnings every 10 seconds that look like:
    // void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
    // Just instantiating an UIWebView before any of the 3rd party libs kick in is enough to fix it.
    // Don't know why, but it works.
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"8.0")) {
        UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
        webView.delegate = nil; // Do something with webView to silence warning
    }
    return YES;
}
```